# What is the meaning of “only other time”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of “only other time” in the sentence:

> But it’s only been a month since we met and the **only other time** I’ve said those words out loud to a girl was over a year ago.

Comment: How many other times has he said those words?

Comment: He said those words only one.

Comment: Right!  The only other time.

Answer (score 1):

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time):

> **Time:** 2.  the point or period when something occurs (= occasion)

"But it’s only been a month since we met and the only other ***occasion*** I’ve said those words out loud to a girl was over a year ago."

The writer is saying that whatever he said to the person he is talking about, he only said it once to a girl a year ago. "Only" means it happened once before and no more than once, and "other" means *that time/occasion that is not this one*.

If it's of any help, the two concepts of *time* as a period and *time* as an occasion are expressed differently in Spanish (*tiempo* and *vez*), Italian (*tempo* and *volta*) and French (*temps* and *fois*).